# Ubuntu Mono ASP.NET Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, mono

```
Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message: : /var/www/GPS/Bin/App_Web_7userbmq.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)

Source Error:

Line 63:             }
Line 64:         }
Line 65:         
Line 66:         [System.Obsolete()]
Line 67:         protected override int AutoHandlers {

Source File: /tmp/www-data-temp-aspnet-0/981a2ec7/App_Web_4ccb964b_0.cs  Lines: 65, 66, 170, 172, 214, 232, 299


Show Detailed Compiler Output:


Show Complete Compilation Source:

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

I m using WINXP and IIS develop the web site,there is no problem with WINXP and ISS.
but my server is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits and Mono 2.10.8.1

i have created a ASP.NET web site with .NET 3.5 setting,
all my C# file will compiled to a .DLL file and the web site use the `DirectMethod` to call .DLL inside function.
Unfortunately, i get this Error. and i can't found any problem with my code.
is that mono support this kind or `DirectMethod`?

p/s:those .DLL file are compiled from WINXP computer, 
do i need to compile which C# file on Ubuntu Server?

[image]

this is my `App_Web_7userbmq.dll` file, after compiled all the C# .cs file will become 1 .dll file only. and asp.net website will use the `DirectMethod` to call the dll function

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: Mono 2.10 is very old, please upgrade

Comment: Generally speaking you need to precompile the site and then deploy the binaries to Mono.

Comment: @LexLi Lex Li can you list out the step by step in answer. i will accept as answer

Comment: @knocte the latest mono is 2.10.x this is the link http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html this is the mono 2.10.8 compatibility http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility and it's is supported .NET 3.5

Comment: in the link you provided, you can clearly read "latest version: 3.2.1"

Comment: @knocte 3.2.1 is only for MAC OSX dude

Comment: wtf are you talking about? a version is a version, the fact that you only have a mac installer doesn't mean that the version doesn't exist for your platform

Comment: you should consult in your distribution's forums (ubuntu in this case) to ask them (or contribute your time to help) to package the version 3.2.1